# Writing a bit flip algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, bit

I am trying to write an algorithm for the following problem.

Problem Statement.

You will be given a list of 32-bits unsigned integers. You are required to output the list of the unsigned integers you get by flipping bits in its binary representation (i.e. unset bits must be set, and set bits must be unset).

The code is as follows:

```
def bit_flip(a):
    return ~a & 0xffffffff

t = raw_input("")
a = map(int, t.split())
map(lambda x: x ^ 0xffffffff, a) 
for i in a:
    print bit_flip(int(i))
```

The input is

```
3
2147483647
1
0
```

The output that i get is 
**4294967292**

whereas the output is supposed to be

```
**2147483648
  4294967294
  4294967295**
```

I am not sure where I am wrong. The output is close to at least one line of the output, but not the same.

Comment: What is the input for that expected output? It seems you're flipping the bits twice (once with `^` and once in `bit_flip`) for each number.

Comment: Isn't this a hackerrank problem?

Comment: yeah it is. I just finished a basic python class and i have been stuck on this problem for a while

Comment: I think in the last question, he was asking about the error he was getting. On this one, he's specifically asking about the algorithm/why his output is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is correct. The 32-bit unsigned complement of `3` is indeed `4294967292`. The full output produced by your program is:

```
4294967292
2147483648
4294967294
4294967295
```

which corresponds correctly to the numbers 3, 2147483647, 1, 0. You can more easily see this if you write them in hex:

```
Dec         Hex       ~Hex      ~Dec
3           3         FFFFFFFC  4294967292
2147483647  7FFFFFFF  80000000  2147483648
1           1         FFFFFFFE  4294967294
0           0         FFFFFFFF  4294967295
```

You seem to be flipping the bits twice, but throwing away the results the first time: `map(lambda x: x ^ 0xffffffff, a)` returns a list containing the flipped values, which you don't assign to anything. If you changed that line to assign the result back to `a`, you wouldn't need `bit_flip` anymore (which also flips the bits, just via a different method):

```
t = raw_input("")
a = map(int, t.split())
a = map(lambda x: x ^ 0xffffffff, a) 
for i in a:
    print i
```

Or even shorter:

```
for i in map(lambda x: int(x) ^ 0xffffffff, raw_input("").split()):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

The list returned by the `map(lambda x: x ^ 0xffffffff, a)` is the answer, but you're not using it.

At least it has the integers with the bits flipped, I'm not sure why the expected output has one fewer element than the input.

Comment: (That might be due to the first number just telling how many proper test cases/inputs are to follow)